# Node Form Not submitting on ctool modal

Tags: 7, nodes, chaos-tool-suite

I have a custom form, on submission of which I am calling ctools modal with a node form(content type: turn).

Code for Custom Form.

```
function _my_module_name_files_listing_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
  $form_state['storage']['values'] = $files;
  $form['download_submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Download'),
    '#submit' => array('_my_module_name_files_download_submit'),
  );
  $form['create_segment'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Create Segment'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-use-modal')),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_my_module_name_files_create_segment',
    ),
  );
  $form['upload_content'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Upload Content'),
    '#submit' => array('_my_module_name_files_upload_content'),
  );
  $form['delete_submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Delete'),
    '#submit' => array('_my_module_name_files_delete_submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Callback code for ajax submission rendering node form.

```
function _my_module_name_files_create_segment($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $form_id = 'turn_node_form';
  ctools_include('node.pages', 'node', '');
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();
  ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
  $destination = 'node/1';
  $form_state = array(
    'ajax' => TRUE,
    'title' => t('Form Title'),
  );
  $node = (object) array(
        'uid' => $user->uid,
        'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
        'type' => 'turn',
        'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
        'status' => TRUE,
  );

  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
  $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper($form_id, $form_state);
  if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
    $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
  }
  if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
    $output = array();
    // Redirect to destination.
    $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('node/8', 0);
  }
  print ajax_render($output);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

**Problem:** 
Node Form is coming fine on modal and hitting save button triggers ajax call but node form does not submit. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm created a node form in a ctools modal and the code I used looks a lot like yours. I don't see anything wrong with it. I wonder if the form on the parent page that launches the ctools modal is getting in the way? It might be worth launching the node form with a link instead of a form and see if that works.

Comment: I thought of keeping it as link instead of submit button but I need submitted values from parent form.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
ctools_include('node.pages', 'node', '');
```

with

```
ctools_form_include_file($form_state, drupal_get_path('module', 'node') . '/node.pages.inc');
```

It's possible that the node.pages.inc file isn't loaded if the form is found from cached data.

Comment: I tried, but it's not working